# Get attribute or elements from page by script in nightwatch

Tags: nightwatch.js

I need a check that class elements was ui-state-active.

```
class="ui-state-default ui-state-active" href="#">15</a>
```

I am trying to using all methods and don't undestand how to write a code:

```
.perform(function () {
    var arrAttr = [];
    var arrCssProp = [];
    var arrValue= [];
    for (i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
      for (j = 1; j < 7; j++) {            
        browser.useXpath();
        browser.getCssProperty('//*[@id="ui-datepicker-div"]/table/tbody/tr[' + i + ']/td[' + j + ']', '.ui-state-default', function (result) {
          arrCssProp[j, i] = result.value;              
        });
        browser.getAttribute('//*[@id="ui-datepicker-div"]/table/tbody/tr[' + i + ']/td[' + j + ']', '.ui-state-default', function (result) {
          arrAttr[j, i] = result.value;
        });
        browser.getValue('//*[@id="ui-datepicker-div"]/table/tbody/tr[' + i + ']/td[' + j + ']', '.ui-state-default', function (result) {
          arrValue[j, i] = result.value;
        });
        browser.useCss();
        writeLogLine('arrAttr:' + i + "|" + j + ' :' + arrAttr);
        console.log('arrAttr:' + i + "|" + j + ' :' + arrAttr);
        writeLogLine('arrCssProp:' + i + "|" + j + ' :' + arrCssProp);
        console.log('arrCssProp:' + i + "|" + j + ' :' + arrCssProp);
        writeLogLine('arrValue:' + i + "|" + j + ' :' + arrValue);
        console.log('arrValue:' + i + "|" + j + ' :' + arrValue);
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: Im trying by elements
    browser.elements('css selector', '#ui - datepicker - div > table > tbody > tr:nth - child('+i+') > td:nth - child('+j+') > a[class="ui-state-default ui-state-active"]', function (result) {
              if (result.value.length > 0) { //element exists 
                writeLogLine('somelement is here and active: ' + result.value)
              }
              else {
                writeLogLine('not here: ' + result.value)
              }
            });

in result i have message     not here: [object Object]

Comment: If you can post a better snippet of the html (the table) you are trying to test I can probably help you figure this one out.

Comment: the problem was in thiкd call. browser.perform.getAttribute. I don't undestern, but when i restricted code whithout perform its work.
this the HTML: 
<td class="  ui-datepicker-current-day" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="11" data-year="2020"><a class="ui-state-default ui-state-active" href="#">1</a></td>

Answer (score 1):

To get the attribute of class, you can write similar code

```
browser.getAttribute(pageObject.getElement('@ui'), "class", function (result) {
if (result.value.indexOf("ui-state-active")!=-1) {
    console.log('class name:' + result.value);
}
else { console.log('class name:' + result.value); }});
```

You can use any locator strategy. To use CSS strategy based on class name, use .ui-state-default along with tagname.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Like in Rohit's example, if you want to use an attribute value, all the commands that rely on it need to be inside the callback. Doing arrCssProp[j, i] = result.value; won't work, since that value will disappear as soon as you exit the callback.

For more info, check out https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/wiki/Understanding-the-Command-Queue